# "Легиники, догваряють, бисьмеся мучили, з жуннов розвела".. Чи це правильний текст пісні? Чи діалект? Google Translate його не розуміє

Tags: значення-слів, діалекти

Сподобалася пісня, але не можу зрозуміти текст: [Vandor.Америка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARQiTnUY2GQ)

Автори запостили такий текст (нижче), але деякі слова мені неясні. Можливо, це якийсь діалект? Може, лемківський діалект?

> 1 куп.) Серед той Америки Корчма мурована
> Пиють пиво **легиники** до білого рана
> Пиють пиво легиники Та ся **догваряють**
> Чому у той Америці Невдобно **ся мають**
> 2 куп.) Ой та тоти долларики тяжко заробляти
> Сімсот метрів у ту землю треба нам копати
> Та ци так нам Бог судив **бисьмеся мучили**
> Бись ми світла сонячного довго не виділи
> Приспів: Америка ,Америка Та дуже невдобна
> Каби море не глибоке Ай хвиля не била
> Америка, Америка Яка ти немила
> Не едного ти чоловіка **з жуннов розвела.**

Вибачаюсь за те, що питаю відразу про кілька слів/фраз.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Може, лемківський діалект?

Діалект, скорѣш за всього, входить до [карпатської ґрупи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2), де також присутній і лемківський. Однак це радше закарпатський.

Сама ж пісня є варіацією чи доробкою до нарідної, котру нп. можна знайти під назвою *Серед тои Америки* в книзѣ — збрінику нарідних пѣсень в 19 вѣцѣ — [*Пісні наших предків*](http://mek.oszk.hu/23400/23468/23468.pdf) від [Антона Годинки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0). Тут записана таким чином:

> Серед тои Америки 
> Корчма мурована. 
> Пиють пиво легіники 
> До білого рана. 
>
> Пиють пиво легіники 
> Та ся догваряють, 
> Чому они в Америці 
> Невдобно ся мають. 
>
> — Ой та тоты долларики 
> Тяжко заробляти. 
> Сімсот сягов попуд землю 
> Треба нам копати. 
>
> Попуд землю, попуд землю, 
> Попуд чорні скалы. 
> Та мы стали такі слабі, 
> Як хробачки малы. 
>
> Та ци так нам пан Бог судив,  
> Бысьмеся мучили,  
> Бисьме світла сонячного  
> Довго не виділи? 
>
> Ще й лампы нам ясно світять, 
> Англик же говорить: 
> — Ладуй, ладуй, русин, кары, 
> Колька тя не вломить! 
>
> Як не вломить — най не вломить 
> Та головка болить, 
> А й кров тече вже из ручок, 
> Хто ми их загоить? 
>
> Най исчезне, святый Боже, 
> Море широкоє, 
> Обы прийшло загоити 
> Соколятко моє.

Сама пѣсня була розібрана в статтѣ *Шлїдом народних пісньох „На штред Америки…”* від [Любомира Медеша](//www.druztvo.org/ruski/promocii/medjesi/index.html) в книзѣ про русинської [закарпатської] [*Творчосц* (1981)](https://zavod.rs/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Tvorcosc-1981.pdf), де можна побачити різні варіяції (можливо, згодом перепишу сюди).

---

> питаю відразу про кілька слів/фраз.

- [Легіник](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), -ка, м. Ум. отъ *ле́гінь*;

  > <sup>Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 4. — С. 461.</sup> 
  > ЛЕ́ГІНЬ, геня, ч., діал. Юнак, парубок. Іван був уже легінь, стрункий і міцний, як смерічка (Коцюб., II, 1955, 313); Шляхом урочисто, в ритм пісні, проходять дівчата і легіні (Стельмах, Над Черемошем.., 1952, 120).

  > <sup>Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 2. — С. 350.</sup> 
  > Легінь, ня, м. = Парубок. Ішов легінь з полонини на нове подвір’є. Гол. III. 216. Приходя до мене молодці-соколи: легіню, на танець, легіню, на поле! Федьк. І. 44. Ум. Легіник. Ой до мене, легіники! Гол. II. 421.

  > <sup>Жайворонок В. В. Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник. — К.: Довіра, 2006. — С. 331.</sup> 
  > ле́гінь (зменшено-пестливе — легі́ник) — народна назва юнака, па­рубка. У зеленій полонині розвилися бучки, І ти легінь, і я легінь — тяг­німося в ключки (коломийка); Ішов легінь з полонини на нове подвір’я (Я. Головацький); Іван був уже ле­гінь, стрункий і міцний, як смерічка (М. Коцюбинський); Котилися во­зи з гори, поламали спиці, Звідали ня легіники, де тут вечорниці (коло­мийка).
- *догваряють* — *договоряють* без [повноголосся](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F);
- *ся мають* — *маються*, чимало, особливо західні, говорів можуть відокремлювати *ся*;
- *бисьмеся мучили*, декотрі слова можуть перетягувати *ймати* і *ся*, а *бись* це друга особа однини до [*би*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%B8#1708); це притамано для західних українських діалектів, це досі ± норма для стандартної польської;
- *жуннов* — скорѣш за всього тут *жоною*, тобто орудний від *жона*, де ненаголошене *о* → *у* (поширене для богатьох діалектів, не лише західних) і *ою* → *ов* (поширене для карпатських), чому подвійне *н* — загадка.